# What is the set of limit points of $E=\{\frac{2n-1}{3n+2}\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, limits, analysis

I'm currently trying to learn about limit points and I really have trouble being sure about how to determine whether a point is a limit point or not.
Limit point definition I'm using is a point for which every neighbourhood contains at least one point (distinct from itself) belonging to a given set.
I'm trying to solve some problems and I'm not sure of my answers. For example am I correct in the bellow question?

On usual metric space of real numbers $(\mathbb{R},d)$; $d=|x-y|$, if we consider $E=\{\frac{2n-1}{3n+2}\} ; n \in \mathbb{N} $,  what would $E'$ the set of limit points be?
Since the sequence in set $E$ is approaching $\frac{2}{3}$ ,it's natural to think of $\frac{2}{3}$ as a limit point. And I think the set doesn't have any other limit point other than $\frac{2}{3}$.is my thought correct? And how do I prove that other than the limit of the sequence we don't have any other limit point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is ok. We say that $x$ is a limit point of $X$ if there are *other* elements of $X$ in every neighbourhood of $x$. In other words, a limit point is a limit of a sequence of elements in $X$. In this case, since every subsequence converges to $\frac 23$, the set of limit points is just $X' = \{\frac 23\}$.

In this case, it is also easy to show that every point in the set is an isolated point (so, not a limit point). If you take any point in the set, say $a_k = \frac{2k-1}{3k+2}$, the closest point in the set is $a_{k+1}=\frac{2k+1}{3k+5}$. So, if you take $\varepsilon < \frac{7}{(3k+2)(3k+5)}$, $a_k$ is the only point  of the set in $B_{\varepsilon}(a_k)$, which means it is a isolated point.